# F# Program is Not Running to Completion

Tags: algorithm, f#, k-means

I am trying to execute an F# script I copied from http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Nearest-Neighbor-Classification-Part-2.aspx as a fs program rather than a script. I have downloaded all the libraries I am using and have tested them in other contexts and they all work. It compiles correctly and sorts the csv file into an array but it does not execute after:

```
let labels = fileAsLines |> Array.map (fun line -> line.[4])
dataset, labels
```

Thank you in advance for any help I have been reading and using this forum frequently and appreciate all the guidance.

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.net
// Code from http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Nearest-Neighbor-Classification-part-2.aspx

open MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Fun.FSharp.Syntax
open MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Fun.FSharp.Inference
open MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Fun.Lib
open MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Maths
open System.IO
open System
open System.Drawing
open MSDN.FSharp.Charting

let distance v1 v2 =
    Array.zip v1 v2
    |> Array.fold (fun sum e -> sum + pown (fst e - snd e) 2) 0.0|> sqrt

let classify subject dataset labels k =
    dataset
    |> Array.map (fun row -> distance row subject)
    |> Array.zip labels
    |> Array.sortBy snd
    |> Array.toSeq
    |> Seq.take k
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.maxBy (fun g -> Seq.length (snd g))
let column (dataset: float [][]) i =
        dataset |> Array.map (fun row -> row.[i])

let columns (dataset: float [][]) =
    let cols = dataset.[0] |> Array.length
    [| for i in 0 .. (cols - 1) -> column dataset i |]

let minMax dataset =
    dataset
    |> columns
    |> Array.map (fun col -> Array.min(col), Array.max(col))

let minMaxNormalizer dataset =
    let bounds = minMax dataset
    fun (vector: float[]) ->
        Array.mapi (fun i v ->
            (vector.[i] - fst v) / (snd v - fst v)) bounds

let normalize data (normalizer: float[] -> float[]) =
    data |> Array.map normalizer

let classifier dataset labels k =
    let normalizer = minMaxNormalizer dataset
    let normalized = normalize dataset normalizer
    fun subject -> classify (normalizer(subject)) normalized labels k

let elections =
    let file = @"C:\Users\Jessica\Dataset\Election2008.txt"
    let fileAsLines =
        File.ReadAllLines(file)
            |> Array.map (fun line -> line.Split(','))
    let dataset =
        fileAsLines
        |> Array.map (fun line ->
            [| Convert.ToDouble(line.[1]);
               Convert.ToDouble(line.[2]);
               Convert.ToDouble(line.[3]) |])
    let labels = fileAsLines |> Array.map (fun line -> line.[4])
    dataset, labels

let evaluate dataset (labels: string []) k prop =
    let size = dataset |> Array.length
    let sample = floor ((float)size * prop) |> (int)
    let testSubjects, testLabels = dataset.[0 .. sample-1], labels.[0..sample-1]
    let trainData = dataset.[sample .. size-1], labels.[sample .. size-1]
    let c = classifier (fst trainData) (snd trainData) k   
    let results =
        testSubjects
        |> Array.mapi (fun i e -> fst (c e), testLabels.[i])
    results
    |> Array.iter (fun e -> printfn "%s %s" (fst e) (snd e))
    let correct =
       results
        |> Array.filter (fun e -> fst e = snd e)
        |> Array.length
    printfn "%i out of %i called correctly" correct sample
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code inside the `let elections` block is being executed is that it's defined as a value and not a function (it does not take any arguments, nor unit `()`). This means it is executed *as it is declared*.

The only code that comes after this in your script declares a function (called `evaluate`; it looks similar, but it takes arguments, and thus is not executed unless something calls it and provides the required arguments), but you do not have any code that does call it.

I believe the easiest changes to make it do what I think you're trying to do are:

1. Remove the `k` and `prop` arguments from the end of the function `evaluate` (these don't seem to be used)
2. At the very end of the script, call the `evaluate` method with the values you have stored in `elections` like this:

   `let dataset, labels = elections`

   `evaluate dataset labels`

It would probably make sense to restructure the code a little, because it seems a little confusing that you have code being executed during the declaration of `elections`, but once you've got the code working, it might be easier to restructure and understand what's happening.